# Phonegap barcode scanner integration from a web page

Tags: cordova, zxing

In my Current Application we have only login page which we are wrapping it up into the phonegap container to make an app. when user opens the app he needs to enter the login details and after sucessful logoin user wil be redirected to another URL and the whole html code which was build on angular stays there.

We would like to keep a bar code scanner in the redirected page(Server side)  and the barcode scanner  Phonegap.js on the client device. But its not working. Please let me know any alernative ways to make it work.

The Possible solutions I searched which are not of a much help

I heard that Zxing [opening barcode scanner from web app](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-From-Web-Pages) has a way of doing this by redirecting the URL but it explains different ways for Android and IOS and did not speak anything about windows phones.

Another Approach is using getUsermedia(). But this works only on chrome in android that too if wrapped in phonegap I doubt it and it has limited connectivity with safari(IOS) and Internet Explorer( Windows Phone 8.0)

The Last Approach I found is using Bridgeit which is making me to use native features of my device from a wep app by installing its Bridge it app. which is working on all devices but the downfall is user should install two apps which the client is not happy about.

Please let me know if there is any way I can make the bar code scanner work from the web app using phonegap that works on Android,IOS and Windows will be of great help thanks in advance.